# Why there is not Spring Boot starter for Spring Webflow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflow, spring-boot-starter

Trying to understand why there is no Spring Boot starter for Spring Webflow. The technology don't looks like deprecated one or I'm wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some discussion about adding a starter for Web Flow in [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/502) where, in 2014, Phil Webb said:

> I think on balance there isn't the audience for a dedicated Web Flow starter so I'm closing this one for now.
>
> Thanks for the suggestion, if we get a lot of comments on this issue we can reconsider.

In the intervening 5 years there has only been a handful of people expressing an interest. As it stands, there doesn't appear to be enough demand.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because it is build on the top of Spring MVC. So if it is autoconfigured, you just have to add the flow dependency and define where is the flow definition. All other is custom, so i think it would be overkill. But this is only my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Check Spring Webflow documentation https://spring.io/projects/spring-webflow , refer to section Spring Boot Config

Answer (score 0):

The issue about creating such starter in Spring-Boot was just declined by Phil Web

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/502

> Although Spring Web Flow still serves a purpose and is being maintained, we don't feel like it's a good candidate to have support out of the box in Spring Boot. We're mainly seeing developers opt for richer Javascript frameworks when they need flow style applications, and we'd rather encourage that direction.Sorry to everyone that's tracking the issue, but we have no plans to add Spring Web Flow support.